# Resize image before uploading in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function for upload image via api in Laravel:

```
private function handleImage($image)
    {
        $exploded = explode(',', $image);

        $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);

        if (Str::contains($exploded[0], 'jpeg')) {
            $extension = 'jpg';
        } else {
            $extension = 'png';
        }
        $fileName = Str::random() . '.' . $extension;

        $path = public_path() . '/images/products/' . $fileName;

        $file = file_put_contents($path, $decoded);

        $image = '/images/products/' . $fileName;

        return $image;
    }
```

How can I resize image to size with max side 500px before uploading?

Comment: If you want to do it _before_ the actual upload happens - then you need to do it on the client side already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  the Intervention Image package in Laravel to resize before uploading.

1. Install the package:

   `composer require intervention/image`
2. Add the below code at the beginning of your file to import the required classes:

   `use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;`

   `use Illuminate\Support\Str;`
3. Modify the **handleImage** method like below:

   ```
   private function handleImage($image)
    {
    $exploded = explode(',', $image);
    $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);
    $image = Image::make($decoded);

    // Resize the image to a maximum size of 500px on the longest side
    $image->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        $constraint->upsize();
    });

    // Set the file extension based on the original image format
    if (Str::contains($exploded[0], 'jpeg')) {
        $extension = 'jpg';
    } else {
        $extension = 'png';
    }

    $fileName = Str::random() . '.' . $extension;
    $path = public_path() . '/images/products/' . $fileName;
    $image->save($path);

    return '/images/products/' . $fileName;
   }
   ```

https://github.com/Intervention/image

Hope it may help

Comment: Thank you so much! This is completely solve my problem